# How can I build C++ ICU Library into iPad Simulator?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, ipad, icu

I am trying to build C++ ICU Library into iPad Simulator. After some work, I successfully build my project with ICU.
But there will be a **crash** when starting the iPad Simulator and no error message shows in console. What's wrong with my build steps?

The crash is on the assembly language below and I don't know what it means.

[Crash Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn3Zy.jpg)

Build Environment:

**Xcode: 8.3.3 iPad Air 2 Simulator**

I just follow the steps in someone's blog. Here are the steps:

1. Download ICU, go into the folder and run the command.

   ```
   mkdir hostbuild
   cd hostbuild 
   sh ../icu/source/runConfigureICU MacOSX
   gnumake
   ```
2. Set some env variable, configure and make.

   ```
   DEVROOT=/XXXX/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
   SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk 
   SYSROOT=$SDKROOT  
   ICU_MYSRC=/Users/lin/ICU/icu 

   export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
   export PATH="/Applications/Xcode_8.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode_8.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
   export CXXPP=  
   export CXXPPFLAGS=  
   export CPPFLAGS="-I$SDKROOT/usr/include/ -I$ICU_MYSRC/source/common/ -I$ICU_MYSRC/source/tools/tzcode/  "  
   export CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT"  
   export CPP="/usr/bin/cpp $CPPFLAGS"  
   export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"   
   export CC="/Applications/Xcode_8.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang"
   export CXX="/Applications/Xcode_8.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++"
   export LDFLAGS="-L$SDKROOT/usr/lib/ -isysroot $SDKROOT -Wl,-dead_strip" 

   mkdir iphonebuild
   cd iphonebuild
   sh ../icu/source/configure --host=x86_64-apple-darwin -with-cross-build=/Users/lin/ICU/hostbuild
   gnumake
   ```
3. Now we get the dylib in iphonebuild/lib. And we need to import them in Xcode.
   In **Build Settings, Other Linker Flags**, Add **-licuuc -licui18n -licutu -licudata -licuio**
   Library Search Path, Add **XXXX/iphonebuild/lib**

   In **Build Phases, Link Binary With Libraries**:
   And the 5 dylib in **XXXX/iphonebuild/lib, libicuuc.60.1.dylib libicui18n.60.1.dylib libicutu.60.1.dylib libicudata.60.1.dylib libicuio.60.1.dylib**
4. Use **install_name_tool** to change the dylib to the correct position in target executable file.
5. Run the project and the error I mentioned above [Crash Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn3Zy.jpg) happens.

Comment: Why don’t you use the ICU library available in macOS?

Comment: Do you mean that ICU library already exists in macOS? Which folder could I find the ICU library as you described? Thanks.

Comment: It does - /usr/lib/

Comment: Do you mean /usr/lib/libicucore.dylib? I will have a try. Thanks.

Comment: What was the stack of the crash? If the 2nd configure had "--enable-debug" you could get a debug build… your commands look right for a cross compile.